# how to load the hidden content box with only url?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I cant find on the internet what i want.

I have this div, in my index.php

```
<div id="navigatie_box" class="about">
    <h1 class="navigate_title">About</h1>
    <div class="about_image"></div>
</div>
```

On click i load content what i have greated in a submap, content/about.php

in this hidden content box:

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

On click the contentbox shows up and load the content/about.php in it.

this is the javascript i use for that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* about click */
    $('.about').click(function() {
    $('.about').hide("fast");
    $('.work').hide("fast");
    $('.cv').hide("fast");
    $('.contact').hide("fast");
    $(".content").slideDown("fast");
    $(".content").load("content/about.php");
    });
```

What i want now is a location in my url, so if i type www.example.com/about, the hidden content box shows up and load the content/about.php in it.

i think it a noob question, but i really cant find it out!

i hope you can help me.

Comment: "so if i type www.example.com/about" What do you mean? If you type it where?

Comment: i mean in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will have to create rewrite rule in .htaccess
to point to index.php file when www.example.com/about is encountered.

Also create rule to send one GET parameter say with "page" in .htaccess.
So when we call www.example.com/about it should redirect like www.example.com/index.php?page=about.

Now in index.php file you will have to check if $_GET['page'] is set than you will have to just show the required content.

Comment: I work in localhost, like this: localhost/example in this map is my index.php and my submaps like content/about.php
Is that relevant for you?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand your question, but i guess you want something like that:

```
var page = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();

$(document).ready(function () {
    /* about click */
    $('.about').click(function () {
        $('.about').hide("fast");
        $('.work').hide("fast");
        $('.cv').hide("fast");
        $('.contact').hide("fast");
        $(".content").slideDown("fast");
        $(".content").load("content/" + page + ".php");
    });
});
```

This is basic snippet and would need some improvement for sure

Comment: What i have now is just basic jquery script.
It loads the content in the specified div, without changing url or something.

So what i want is if i type www.example.com/about it loads the content/about in the specified div. without clicking on .about button in my index.php

I also work in localhost, like this: localhost/example in this map is my index.php and my supmaps like content/about.php

Comment: What u dont understand? i want to make it clear to you:)